# Событие при body.appendChild

Tags: javascript

В JavaScript есть много обработчиков событий: onload, 'DOMContentLoaded' и т.п. Но все они (из тех, что я знаю) срабатывают при загрузке страницы. А могу ли я создать элемент, вставить его, и отследить его прогрузку:

```
div = document.createElement('div');
div.onEVENT = function() {}
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: Для чего вам отслеживать добавления элемента? Вы не доверяете JS?

Comment: DOMSubtreeModified